# Laravel Model coming through with wrong integer after creation - but fine elsewhere

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have an api connected to a form which makes an instance of a Laravel class, saves it to the database, and returns the json:

```
    $record = $request->all();
    $record['client_id'] = $client->id;
    $record['price'] = $record['price'] * 100; // price sent in pounds, needs converting to pence

    $newRecord = CustomerServicePrice::create($record);
    return response()->json($newRecord->toJson());
```

I'm not using any unusual laravel packages or sql, it's all just normal, Innodb.

So, when `$record['price']` comes in, it's set to a string, '2.30' -- my code, as you can see, multiplies it by 100 before saving it to an integer column in the database.

The record gets recorded to the database perfectly, as 230. But, for some reason, `$newRecord->price` is coming out as 229. If I fetch the record via another api and render it, it renders correctly as 230 - it's only upon creation that it returns me the incorrect 229 value, and it doesn't happen with all numbers -- if I submit '2.40' it will correctly show me 240, it's isolated to some values only.

If you've come across this before, I'd love some help.

Comment: `dd($newRecord->price)` gives something like "(string) 229"? and when you look in the db with tools like heidisql/phpmyadmin the value is 230?

Comment: Roland that's right. Really strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a rounding error. Because it is coming in as a decimal, the database is having a floating point error that presumably causes it to sometimes round down to 229. My suggestion is to cast the command to an integer with

```
$record['price'] = (int) ($record['price'] * 100);
```

or something similar and see if that fixes the issue.

Edit: Try what Beniamin H suggested below using Round()

Comment: Unfortunately, `when $record['price']` is '2.30', `(int) ($record['price'] * 100);` is still giving me 229. I have no idea why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's because how float numbers are handled by most programming languages and computers in general. The number 2.30 cannot be precisely represented as a sum of powers of 2. For example in JS:

```
'2.30' * 100
```

gives:

```
229.99999999999997
```

You can read more about it for example [here](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

There are many work around solutions, like rounding, using dedicated math libs (like [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) in php) and others. In your case simple:

```
round($record['price'] * 100.0);
```

should solve the issue.